# Testing innerHTML for partial string

Tags: javascript, html, autohotkey

Alright, I'm attempting to cycle through html elements within an iFrame to capture certain fields within a report.  The structure of the HTML is as follows

```
html>frameset>frame>html>body>table>tbody>tr>td.set2>pre>(Text)
```

The JS I'm using to capture the .innerHTML is below

```
document.parentWindow.frames("Frame"B).document.all.tags("pre")[x].innerHTML
```

Now the above line will allow me to capture the innerHTML of the 'pre' element that contains the report name and the information I'm looking for.  I'm currently working in the IE console to get my JS right before I move it to AutoHotKey but below is the function I'm attempting to use to cycle through all 'pre' elements

```
function preTest(){
for(x=0; x < pre.length; x++){
    if(pre[x].innerHTML = "CLMPRUN"){
      return pre[x].innerHTML;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
  }
};
```

Now, the problem is that when I run the function, it only returns "CLMPRUN".  Whenever I change the test in the if statement, it returns as if I've declared pre[x].innerHTML as a variable.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparisons in `if` statements require the use of `==` or `===` operators. Using only one `=` means that you're assigning the value to the property.

Comment: So, I've added the correct comparison '==', but I'm still not getting the results I want.

Comment: I have to figure out these overflow comments, anyway, I need to figure out how to search the entire innerHTML of the 'pre' element and if it has the right string, i.e. "CLMPRUN" to return the innerHTML of that 'pre' element.

Comment: You can always use the `indexOf` method to check if the string is contained. You'll end up with something like this: `if(pre[x].innerHTML.indexOf("CLMPRUN") >= 0) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this line: 'pre[x].innerHTML = "CLMPRUN"' You are assigning the text instead of comparing. That's why it keeps returning "CLMPRUN".

Please check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness